# Problemas en Custom Dialog (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Buenas Tengo un problema con el custom Dialog, lo que pasa es que estaba usando FindViewById() y no tenia problema, estaba cambiando todo el codigo a DataBinding y Ahora el Dialog no se muestra completo

No he tocado nada solo cambiando todo a databinding porque me parece mas practico a la hora de trabajar, todo lo demás del programa esta trabajando de forma correcta, el unico problema es el Custom Dialog

El xml del dialog es el siguiente

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/blue">

        <TextView
            android:paddingTop="6dp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Añadir Paciente"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/cédula"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/dialogCI"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:inputType="number"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/IDdispositivo"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/dialogID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:text="@string/nota"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/red"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialogCancell"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:text="@string/Cancelar"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialogAcept"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Y el codigo de del dialog es el siguiente

```
 private fun showDialog() {
        val dialogBinding : DialogBinding = DialogBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this))
        val dialog = Dialog(this)
        dialog.setContentView(dialogBinding.root)
        dialog.setCancelable(false)
        val ci =dialogBinding.dialogCI
        val id = dialogBinding.dialogID
        val cancell = dialogBinding.dialogCancell
        val add = dialogBinding.dialogAcept

        cancell.setOnClickListener {
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
```

Por Favor Ayuda! Necesito resolver este tema para mi trabajo de grado, y cualquier otra recomendacion es bien recibida.

Comment: cómo se muestra el dialog y cómo quieres que se muestre? Probaste con el overload de `inflate` que tiene tres parámetros?

Comment: Hola Gracias por responer, Ya puse resolverlo, cambie el Dialog por un alertDialog y funciona mucho mejor